# Rails has_many belongs_to relationships

Tags: ruby-on-rails, has-many, belongs-to

I've got a pretty basic problem but can't seem to get it to work right.

here's the setup -

```
class Recipe < ActiveRecord::Base
 has_many :recipeIngredients
 has_many :ingredients :through => :recipeIngredients
end

class Ingredient < ActiveRecord::Base
 has_many :recipeIngredients
 has_many :recipes :through => :recipeIngredients
end

class RecipeIngredients < ActiveRecord::Base
 belongs_to :recipe
 belongs_to :ingredients
end
```

Each ingredient has an ID and a name, Recipe has an ID and a Title, RecipeIngredients has recipe_id, ingredient_id, amount

When I attempt to render using

```
@recipe = Recipe.find(params[:id])
render :json => @recipe, :include => :ingredients
```

I get my ingredients, but can't access the amount or name from RecipeIngredients. - this outputs

```
{
    "list_items": {
        "id": 1,
        "title": "Foo",
        "description": null,
        "ingredients": [
            {
                "id": 1
            },
            {
                "id": 2
            },
            {
                "id": 3
            },
            {
                "id": 4
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

How can I make the relationship between ingredients and recipeIngredients so that when calling :ingredients I get something like -

```
{
 "id":1,
 "name":"foo",
 "amount":"2 oz"
}
```

thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You didn't define many-to-many according to Rails. The correct solution is (**file names** should be as described):

**app/models/recipe.rb**

```
class Recipe < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :recipe_ingredients
  has_many :ingredients, :through => :recipe_ingredients
end
```

**app/models/ingredient.rb**

```
class Ingredient < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :recipe_ingredients
  has_many :recipes, :through => :recipe_ingredients
end
```

**app/models/recipe_igredient.rb**

```
class RecipeIngredient < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :recipe
  belongs_to :ingredient
end
```

Also verify, your join table defined, as following:

**db/12345_create_recipe_ingredints.rb**

```
class CreateRecipeIngredients < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :recipe_ingredients, id: false do |t|
      t.references :recipe
      t.references :ingredient
    end
    add_index :recipe_ingredients, :recipe_id
    add_index :recipe_ingredients, :ingredient_id
  end
end
```

After doing this, make a test in your console:

```
recipe = Recipe.first # should contain data
igredient = Ingredient.first # should contain data
recipe.ingredients << ingredient
recipe.inspect
```

If everything works correctly and **recipe.inspect** contains **ingredient**, json should be correct

Comment: ROCK AND ROLL! Thanks so much!

Comment: One question - So If I wanted to access a new column called amount in my recipe_ingredients how would I do that? Currently this works - but is the same situation I had before, I can't seem to get into the amount data that's within the recipe_ingredient....

Comment: recipe_ingredients is join table. You don't need to access it. If you want to access amount of ingredient, you should do it as following: recipe.ingredients[i].amount. Note: ingredients is array